# x!!=y!, any integer solutions but trivial ones?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

Question says it all, are there any non trivial solutions? Wolfram gives those:

x=[image]

But I wonder, if in fact there aren't any, is there any way we can prove that? I ask only becuase I am curious. Thank you.

Comment: what I meant is are there any integers so the equaiton holds. For example is 1227! equal to any x!!. I understand that "single factorial" is injective becaue 1!<2!<3!... but similiarly for double factorials 1!!<2!!<3!!...  but how does it prove that somewhere out there there isn't a pair of integers for which x!=y!!. Sorry if I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: What is $(-1)!$?

Comment: that is a very good question... So, let's rephrase... what if we restrict domain to be natural numbers?

Comment: The factorial function is injective, and therefore if $x!! = y!$, $x! = y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there are not.  If $x$ is odd, then $x!!$ is odd so you only have $y=0$ or $y=1$ and $x=1$.  If $x$ is even, say $x=2k$, then $x!!=2^k\cdot k!$.  So that means that $k<x$.  But then $y!=2^k\cdot k!$ implies that $k+1, k+2, \ldots y$ have only factors of $2$, which is impossible because $2^k$ is too large.  So you only have the trivial solution $2!!=2!$.

Comment: I don't understand. $x!!$ is odd only when $x$ is $0$ or $1$. Also, the equality $(2k)!! = 2^k k!$ is not correct. Take, e.g., $k=2$.

Comment: @Justthisguy Double factorial is not the same as taking factorial twice; it's much more like a factorial, except you decrease the numbers by 2 instead of 1. $5!!=5\cdot3\cdot1$, for example.

Comment: perfect answer. thank You